# Google Maps Driving Directions - Insert Points from a Database

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a simple form working to display driving directions from point A to point B in Google Maps.  I have a database with custom locations (lat/lon).  I want to include any points from my database within 1 mile of the route generated by Google Maps from point A to point B into the driving directions.

Example - Traveling from Tulsa to Nashville will display those directions - but I have a store in Little Rock that I want to auto-embed into those generated directions - if not as an embedded stop, as a point of interest.

Can't find anything about it in the API or online.

Is this possible?  Happy to provide more info if needed.

Thanks!

A

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [RouteBoxer](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/routeboxer/) class from the [Google Maps Utility library](http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/wiki/Libraries).

> This class creates a set of LatLngBounds that are guaranteed to
>   enclose every point within a given distance of a Polyline. It is
>   intended to support adding Search along a route to an application
>   backed by a spatial database that supports bounds queries.

It will give you an array of rectangles that you can use to see if they contain one or more of the stores. You could then either list the stores that are close, or insert the stores as waypoints and regenerate the route.

Comment: Thanks Mark!  Looks like exactly what I need.  I will get into this soon and report back (and mark as the answer).  Appreciate the response!  - J